# I want to create a View bigger than the screen

Tags: react-native

I want to create a View bigger than the screen with react native directly to works in android and ios, why do i want to create it? because i want to create a swipe at the item on the list

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

const ViewBoxesWithColorAndText = () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "red", flex: 0.5 }} />
      <Text>Hello World!</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

export default ViewBoxesWithColorAndText;
```

Comment: Need more information regarding your issue, with a minimal code to reproduce. Do you have a list and want to scroll the list to see all the items?

Comment: Do you mean you want to scroll throw Views then use -> scrollview

Comment: like this library, i dont want to use libraries https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-swipe-list-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the screen dimensions.

```js
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const Window = Dimensions.get('window')
const Screen = Dimensions.get('screen')
const WIDTH = Screen.width
const HEIGHT = Screen.height
const FONT_SCALE = Window.fontScale
const SCREEN_SCALE = Window.scale
```

I hope, these what you wanted.

Comment: i want to create a View bigger than the screen in x axis